# Drop method not working (VBA,Visio)

Tags: vba, methods, visio, shapes

I need to drop a shape that i get from a masters. It was working really wwell, but wheni changed some names in my library it is not working anymore
this is what i did:

```
    ...
    Case "4", "5", "10", "1006", "1007", "1001"
    Set Filage =Application.ActiveDocument.Pages.Item(la_page).Drop(Application.Documents.Item("Controleur-e++.vssx").Masters.ItemU("filage#" & CInt(final(5, 0, i))), x0, y0_i)
```

...
where  la_page is a string that represents the page name

final(5,0,i) is a string for example "1001"
xo and y0_i are two numbers that set the position where i wanna drop the shape

N.B: my shape name is filage#1001

Thanks for your answers

Comment: i think my problem is not the code but rather my stencils. in fact, i changed the name of my shapes for example filage1 to filage1001 and im using the new names in my code.I think however visio call the shapes with their old name. Is it possible so visio calls the shapes with their new names?

Comment: Read more about difference [Name and NameU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2006/07/27/name-and-nameu/)

Comment: @Surrogate Thanks a lot it worked!!!